# Jsreport XLSX recipie: Saving jsreport response to an excel file

Tags: jsreport

I am trying to save the response received from jsreport API. How to save jsreport response to an excel file?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am trying the same but all I get is a zip file containing xml.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a little knowledge of JSReport.

First of all, make sure that you [set up your report to run as an excel report](https://jsreport.net/learn/xlsx) and that you have `xlsx` selected in the template type.

[image: xlsxTemplate]

I assume you've already done all of that.

Next, in [the JSON object that you send to JSReport](https://jsreport.net/learn/api), you will probably have created something like this:

```
let dataOptions = { 
   template: { 
      shortid: 'xx2346kn' 
   }, 
   data: reportData 
}
```

Add an `options` property so that you end up with this:

```
let dataOptions = { 
    template: { 
        shortid: 'xx2346kn' 
    }, 
    data: reportData,
    options: {
        preview: true
    }
}
```

Assuming you've set everything else up correctly, this will

> save jsreport response to an excel file

in your default downloads location.